# What is the best method to test the null hypothesis on volatile data?

Tags: variance, t-test, p-value, t-distribution

I am trying to find a good method to test the null hypothesis(H0) on two unpaired samples. Those samples come from two different HTTP Servers and the unit I'm using is req/30s (requests concluded in 30 seconds).

Even a well-established server is expected to have a standard deviation of 50 requests. I have tried to use the Student's t-test to validate the null hypothesis, however, the following dataset it shows a p-value lower than the threshold of 0.05

```py
A1 = [
  4670, 4646, 4612, 4618, 4646,
  4609, 4623, 4629, 4566, 4628,
  4582, 4636, 4621, 4574, 4624,
  4563, 4651, 4642, 4586, 4621,
  4606, 4628, 4575, 4631, 4646,
  4600, 4594, 4661, 4568, 4611
]

B1 = [
  4630, 4655, 4652, 4633, 4637,
  4661, 4625, 4680, 4647, 4639,
  4633, 4661, 4638, 4621, 4630,
  4682, 4703, 4665, 4652, 4648,
  4673, 4651, 4669, 4646, 4612,
  4654, 4651, 4619, 4637, 4620
]
st.ttest_ind(A1, B1)
# Ttest_indResult(statistic=-4.855056212284194, pvalue=9.47100493260572e-06)
```

In my previous question [Student's t-test on "high" magnitude numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594784/students-t-test-on-high-magnitude-number), I could understand that the data are clustered a low variance means statically significant.
However, for my use case, this variance shouldn't reject the null hypothesis. I thought about comparing the means between two samples and if the difference was less than X, the hypothesis would be true. However, since the data is volatile I can't trust the mean, because sometimes, I can get results in a large range (4000 ~ 10000) for instance.

What methods the recommended to test if those two samples are statically significant considering those limitations?

Comment: If you are concerned about the mean being sensitive to outliers, you might consider if the median is more appropriate for your task. // [Some argue in favor of considering the mean *because* of its sensitivity.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14210/if-mean-is-so-sensitive-why-use-it-in-the-first-place/14218#14218)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responses to [your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594784/students-t-test-on-high-magnitude-numbers)†, address a hypothesis test on the means for this sample data.

It sounds like you are trying to make a hypothesis test mean something other than than what does.

Or that you know what answer you want, and are trying to find a statistical "test" that will confirm this intuition.

A few notes on your question:

"*However, for my use case, this variance shouldn't reject the null hypothesis*".  Honestly, if you have already decided what conclusion you want to reach, you don't need to conduct any test. Especially in the case of two-sample data, your intuition as to what conclusion you should draw may be more preceptive than a test of statistical significance.

"*I thought about comparing the means between two samples and if the difference was less than X, the hypothesis would be true*".  If this is what you want, you can do this.  It doesn't require any special statistical knowledge; it would be just what you said: "The threshold for some conclusion is if mean of *A* and mean of *B* are < *X* or not."

"*However, since the data is volatile I can't trust the mean*". If this is a concern, you are free to use a trimmed mean or perhaps the median or maybe the geometric mean, or some other statistic of central tendency.

---

† Really, essentially duplicate question.

Comment: For this specific use case, I do have my conclusion, but I'm still testing it because my intention is to include that approach in an automated tool. Hence, what I'm doing is validating if the p-value is reliable from my business perspective or as you wrote, I'm trying to find a statical test that will confirm this intuition.

I'm sorry for the duplicated question, I was instructed to create a new question if my concern differs from the original question.

Comment: @Rafael , no worries.  One thing is that hypothesis tests mean less than we often imply that they do.  I mean, a *t*-test determines if there's a detectable difference in means relative to the variability in the data.  If the same size is large enough, and there is some real difference in the means, then the *t*-test should return a significant result.  Whether this difference in means is of any practical importance is an entirely different question.